Kronecker product and Vectorization to form a needed equation
(1)$$(\mathbf{R}_{B} \otimes \mathbf{R}_{A}) \, \text{vec}(\mathbf{R}_X) - \text{vec}(\mathbf{R}_Y) = 0$$
(2)
$${\left(-\mathbf{I} \quad \mathbf{R}_{B} \otimes \mathbf{R}_{A}\right) \begin{pmatrix} \text{vec}(\mathbf{R}_Y) \\ \text{vec}(\mathbf{R}_X) \end{pmatrix} = 0}$$
I dont understand how the second form is achieved. What steps are needed to get to (2)?
The symbol $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. $\text{vec}(\mathbf{A})$ represents the column-wise vectorization of matrix A. I could just use (2) but I would like to understand how (2) is achieved. $\mathbf{R}_{A}$, $\mathbf{R}_{B}$, $\mathbf{R}_{X}$ and $\mathbf{R}_{Y}$ are rotation matrices of size (3x3) or (2x2).
The problem started with:
$$\mathbf{R}_{A} \mathbf{R}_X \mathbf{R}_{B}^T = \mathbf{R}_Y$$ and used $$(\mathbf{B}^T \otimes \mathbf{A}) \, \text{vec}(\mathbf{X}) = \text{vec}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}) = \text{vec}(\mathbf{C})$$ to get to (1).
Thanks for your help!

$\sf Equation\ 2$ is just $\sf Equation\ 1$ rewritten using partitioned (aka block) matrices.
